# How to reference controls located on different Tabs (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, tabs, tabcontrol

I have an application written in VB.NET that reads data from a file and displays the data on the screen.

Depending on the data in the file, the program has a TabControl with up to 3 tabs and each tab in turn has a DataGridView for displaying data. For example I have a TabControl that has a tab called "Saturday" and a tab called "Sunday".

The problem I am having is that when I read data from a file, the program displays all the data on the Saturday's tab grid because I am not sure how to reference the Grid on the Sunday tab.

To add the DataGridView I am using the following code:

```
Grid = New DataGridView
Grid.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
Grid.Name = "Grid" & TabControl.SelectedIndex
Grid.Tag = "Grid" & TabControl.SelectedIndex
```

And this is how I am reading the data in:

```
If reader.GetAttribute("controltype") = "Tab" Then
    SelectedTab = reader.Name
End If

If reader.Name = "cell" Then
y = y + 1
Grid.Rows(i).Cells(y).Style.BackColor = Color.FromName(reader.ReadElementString("cell"))
End If
```

What I almost want to do is something like (pseudocode):

```
SelectedTab.Grid.Rows(i).Cells(y).Style.BackColor = Color.FromName(reader.ReadElementString("cell"))
```

However when I use the above code it complains:

> 'Grid' is not a member of 'String'

I hope you understand the issue. Let me know if you need clarification

Comment: Looks pretty weird to me... So..Why and when do you add a GridView to the _current_ tab? Why not at design time? Are the tabs not fixed? Is this code called only once really? Do you add the new Grid to any Controls Collection anywhere?

Comment: @KekuSemau I export the data to an XML file and then I reload it. When you first open the program, the screen is blank, nothing there at all. Then based on the XML file, I add tabs and DataGridViews. Think of it as a project plan. A plan for Saturday and a plan for Sunday. Each day contains different data. i,e. Saturday 9-10am task name is "Check Progress" for example. I can't add grid and tabs at design time because I am not sure how many I will need. Hope that made it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a little unclear. However, it appears to me that the following line:

```
If reader.GetAttribute("controltype") = "Tab" Then
    SelectedTab = reader.Name
End If
```

is creating at least one problem. It looks like you are attempting to refer to a Tabpage control by the string representation of its name, but unless I missed something, what that line is actually doing is trying to make a tabpage control type("SelectedTab") refer to a string type. If that is the case, then you will want to try this instead:

```
If reader.GetAttribute("controltype") = "Tab" Then
    TabControl1.SelectedTab = TabControl1.TabPages(reader.name)
End If
```

It is a little hard to tell from the code you have posted, but that might get you headed down the right path.

++++++++++++

UPDATE: It appears from your code that you are naming each DGV control by appending the index of the tab on which it is located to the string "grid." I am going to assume that you are using a class member variable named "SelectedTab" to represent the current tab selected in the control. I will assume that at the top of your class you have done something like this:

```
'Form-or-class scoped memebr variables:
Private SelectedTab As TabPage
Private SelectedGrid As DataGridView
```

You should be able to refer to the active grid control using something like this:

```
Private Sub TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged

    ' Set SelectedTab member variable to refer to the new selected tab page:
    SelectedTab = TabControl1.SelectedTab

    ' Set the SelectedGrid to refer to the grid control hosted on the selected tab page:
    SelectedGrid = TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls("Grid" & TabControl1.SelectedIndex.ToString())
End Sub
```

From here, you should be able to use the member variable for SelectedGrid to refer to the grid present on which ever tab page is selected in your tab control.

It is challenging to address your concerns with only fragments of your code. If you have additional difficulties, please post more of your code, so we can better see what else is going on.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Your answer makes sense to me. Using your code will enable me to correctly set the selected tab. However the reason why I am storing it in a variable is so that further down the code I can do something like: `SelectedTab.Grid.rows(i).add(...)` . Because as I mentioned before, there might be multiple tabs and my code currently doesn't work with multiple tabs. Or do I just do something like: `Grid.Rows(i).add(...)` expecting the code to refer to the grid on the currently selected tab?

Comment: I will test your approach later on and get back to you. From just looking at the code, it looks like that is exactly what I need but just want to test it to make sure it works. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I would go about something like this. Maybe you can simply use a DataSet to load the XML data in one line (if they have been saved with `DataSet.WriteXML` before).

```
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim p As TabPage
    Dim gv As DataGridView

    ds.ReadXml("F:\testdata.xml")
    For i As Integer = TabControl1.TabPages.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        TabControl1.TabPages.RemoveAt(i)
    Next

    For Each dt As DataTable In ds.Tables
        p = New TabPage(dt.TableName)
        gv = New DataGridView
        ' ... configure the gv here...
        gv.AutoGenerateColumns = True
        gv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        ' ...
        gv.DataSource = dt
        TabControl1.TabPages.Add(p)
        p.Controls.Add(gv)
    Next
```

Comment: the data has been saved using XMLStreamWriter. I am not sure how to achieve the functionality above with my code.

Comment: Hmm, please explain again: 1) What's your data? Are they table-like or some other data that refer to single cells? Are there several tables in the file or how do you _logically_ know what tab page you want to do something on? 2) Explain again what you read from the file and what's the logical steps of what you want to do then (in what tab, in what cell, ...). (Better add this via Editing at your question above).

Comment: this is the content of the file: [link](http://pastebin.com/2CjGdGNY)  As you can see from the code, I know how many tab pages I will need but I cannot add them at design time, They need to be added programmatically